# Filter rows based on one column then check if another column's values are in the specific list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given a toy building data as follow, I want to check when `type == 'other'`, whether there are some irregular values (which means not in `Hall` or `Parking space`) for `name` in the dataframe.

```
    id    type                          name
0    1  office  Hessel, Macejkovic and Nader
1    2  office                Stiedemann LLC
2    3  office                     Grant Ltd
3    4  office                Anderson Group
4    5  retail                   MacDanald's
5    6  retail                      Wallmart
6    7  retail                      Wallmart
7    8   other                          Hall
8    9   other                 Parking space
9   10   other                 Parking space
10  11   other                   Roberts PLC
```

For the dataset above, I hope it create a new column `indication` and returns `N` for the last row, since `Roberts PLC` is not in `['Hall', 'Parking space']`.

```
    id    type                          name indication
0    1  office  Hessel, Macejkovic and Nader        NaN
1    2  office                Stiedemann LLC        NaN
2    3  office                     Grant Ltd        NaN
3    4  office                Anderson Group        NaN
4    5  retail                   MacDanald's        NaN
5    6  retail                      Wallmart        NaN
6    7  retail                      Wallmart        NaN
7    8   other                          Hall        NaN
8    9   other                 Parking space        NaN
9   10   other                 Parking space        NaN
10  11   other                   Roberts PLC          N
```

Code I have used which need to edit:

```
m = df1.loc[df1['type'].isin(['other'])]
if m['name'].str.contains('Hall|Parking space', na = False).any():
    print('')
else:
    print('N')
```

Thanks for your kind help at advance.

**Plus:**

For print the indication:

```
if (df["type"].eq("other")) & (~df["name"].str.contains('Hall|Parking space', na = False).any()):
    print('Other type data has irregular data')
else:
    print('No irregular data found in other type data')
```

Out:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the assignment directly:

```
df.loc[(df["type"].eq("other"))&(~df["name"].str.contains('Hall|Parking space', na = False)), "indication"] = "N"

print (df)

    id    type                          name indication
0    1  office  Hessel, Macejkovic and Nader        NaN
1    2  office                Stiedemann LLC        NaN
2    3  office                     Grant Ltd        NaN
3    4  office                Anderson Group        NaN
4    5  retail                   MacDanald's        NaN
5    6  retail                      Wallmart        NaN
6    7  retail                      Wallmart        NaN
7    8   other                          Hall        NaN
8    9   other                 Parking space        NaN
9   10   other                 Parking space        NaN
10  11   other                   Roberts PLC          N
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want print the indication phrase instead of creating new column as I updated in the question? How could I modify my code?

Comment: Use `df.loc[(df["type"].eq("other"))&(~df["name"].str.contains('Hall|Parking space', na = False))]`.

Comment: Sorry, i need it print out a phrase `'Other type data has irregular data'` for the example data.

Comment: If you need a statement, you can use `if not df.empty; print ('Other type data has irregular data')`.

Comment: Yes, but i've tried so by `if (df["type"].eq("other")) & (~df["name"].str.contains('Hall|Parking space', na = False).any()): print('Other type data has irregular data') else: print('No irregular data found in other type data')`, but it raises a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: You are calling `any` at the wrong place. Use `((df["type"].eq("other"))&(~df["name"].str.contains('Hall|Parking space', na = False))).any()`.